# Error while installing Laravel Horizon on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-horizon

In Windows 10 Home Basic I get the following error while installing Laravel Horizon.

I have PHP version 7.1.9 running on Xampp.

```
$ composer require laravel/horizon
```

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1 :  - laravel/horizon v1.0.8 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the [PCNTL PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/book.pcntl.php) is not installed, and that Horizon requires a PHP environment that provides this extension.

The PCNTL extension provides an API for Unix-style process management and signaling. Because of its inherent focus on facilities only available in Unix- or Linux-like operating systems, this extension does not support Windows as described in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/intro.pcntl.php):

> **Note:** This extension is not available on Windows platforms.

From this API, Laravel Horizon uses the [async signal handling](http://php.net/manual/function.pcntl-async-signals.php) feature that's new to PHP 7.1 to manage queue worker processes. For this reason, Horizon does not currently support Windows, and Windows developers need to use a virtual environment, such as [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/homestead), to install and run Horizon.

At the time of writing, this reflects the [official position of the Laravel team](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/78) regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add "laravel/horizon": "^4.0", in composer.json and for install Horizon run command

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

For start Horizon in windows you can use command

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=default,horizon
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `composer.json` and under `config`, add this

```
"platform": {
        "ext-pcntl": "8.0",
        "ext-posix": "8.0"
 }
```

So, from the next time, you won't have to use `--ignore-platform-reqs` anymore.